# Own DynDNS Server?

Tags: dns, home-server, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

Is there any own dynamic DNS server available?

I have one public server that runs DNS for my domain (running tinydns) and I want to update it with the current IP of my home router?

Are there any ready-to-use solutions available or do I have to code my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some solutions available, but it looks like you'll have to do a bit of work to get them going.

http://dave.frop.net/simple_dynamic_dns_tinydns_php

Comment: Great! I was already thinking about how to implement my own solutions and your link points to a very similar one (.. but I would never use PHP ;-) ).
The data file concepts makes it very easy to update tinydns.